# How do I retain navigation elements after ModelState.IsValid fails?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, validation

I have the following pair of controller methods for Editing.

The initial call is no problem, and correctly displays the model and properties from two of the child/navigation objects (1:1 relationships).

When I try to save, if the model is valid there is no problem.

When it is Invalid though, I get a null reference in my view referencing any of the child/navigation properties - which were correctly there in the original view.

```
public ActionResult Edit(int id)
    {
        var reportcustomerlimit = db.ReportCustomerLimits.Single(r => r.Id == id);
        return View(reportcustomerlimit);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(ReportCustomerLimit reportcustomerlimit)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.ReportCustomerLimits.Attach(reportcustomerlimit);
            reportcustomerlimit.ReportCustomer.Verified = false;
            ReportGenerator.ClearAllReportsZip();
            db.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(reportcustomerlimit, EntityState.Modified);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index", new { id = reportcustomerlimit.CustomerNumber });
        }
        else
        {
            //What do I do here?
        }
        return View(reportcustomerlimit);
    }
```

What am I missing?

(Note: The validation is normally done client side, and stops the form being submitted - but I've turned off javascript to test the server side validation works as well)

Comment: So, even if there are any validation errors, you need to display the child navigation properties in view. am i right ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(ReportCustomerLimit reportcustomerlimit)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.ReportCustomerLimits.Attach(reportcustomerlimit);
            reportcustomerlimit.ReportCustomer.Verified = false;
            ReportGenerator.ClearAllReportsZip();
            db.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(reportcustomerlimit, EntityState.Modified);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index", new { id = reportcustomerlimit.CustomerNumber });
        }
        else
        {
            var reportcustomerlimit = db.ReportCustomerLimits.Single(r => r.Id == id);
            return View(reportcustomerlimit);
        }

    }
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Yes, pointed me in the right direction...I actually called the db.xxxx.Attach() method BEFORE the ModelState.IsValid, which also worked :)